# Unable to parse this json in jquery 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ashx

I tried but i was unable to parse this json object which comes from an ashx page.I use javascript serializer to serialize list.I showed the returned json just as it is but when i tried to parse it showed only [object Object],[object Object].
If i change the result to this at ashx page and return string 
 "{ \"Appointment\":"+ return +"}" then jquery doesn't see the post as success and fails to parse it.I use jquery 1.7.1.min.js but there was no way of parsing it.These are the methods i used and the json object i tried to parse

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getappointment.ashx",
            data: { StartTime: timec },
            dataType: "Text",
            success: function (msg) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                for (var i in result) {
                    alert(result[i].appointmentID)
                }
            }


        });
```

1)

```
 parsed= $.secureEvalJSON(JSON.stringify(json));
   alert(parsed.Appointment[1].appointmentID);
```

2)

```
$.each(json.Appointment, function (i, app) {
      alert(json.app.appointmentID.toString());
```

3)

```
var test = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                alert(test[0].appointmentID);
```

4)

```
$.each(msg, function () {
  $.each(this, function (k, v) {
   ...
           });
    });
```

Json object

```
[{"appointmentID":"4","coachid":"1","equipmentid":"1","starttime":"18.03.2012 19:14:28","endtime":"18.03.2012 19:14:28"},
{"appointmentID":"8","coachid":"1","equipmentid":"1","starttime":"18.03.2012 19:00:00","endtime":"18.03.2012 19:14:28"}]
```

Comment: The JSON you've shown is parsed perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/vSA2y/

Comment: $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getappointment.ashx",
            data: { StartTime: timec },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                alert(result);
            }


        });

Comment: that one gives [object Object],[object Object] and then "null".

Comment: so? how is it related to the question? The JSON **is valid**

Comment: @zerkms the json looks valid but i'm unable to get the values it writes null to the console either.I showed the whole function so guys might understand if i'm doing anything wrong

Comment: as long as you specify `dataType: "json"` - you should get a valid object as a result. Look what server **actually** returned you using your favorite web developer tools.

Comment: @zerkms well when i provided the json as string in jquery it worked.then i changed it back to result of success data but it showed so null.So i think those ' made the difference.Changing datatype to text solved the problem now it works thanks.if you provide it as answer i will mark it.

Comment: change it back to `json` and **DON'T PARSE MANUALLY**, because there is a valid object in a `response` already

Comment: but it doesn't work when i make datatype:json

Comment: show the whole `success` callback body

Comment: @zerkms i added it to the question

Comment: add `datatype: 'json'` and I told you **DON'T PARSE MANUALLY**, because there is a valid object. `console.log(msg);`

Comment: @zerkms I did you what you said.Thought i can see the result in log I can't get the values in jquery, how am i going to loop and assign them?

Comment: `msg` is just an array - use it as **any other** array. `for (var i in msg) { console.log(msg[i]); }`

Comment: added it as an answer ;-) And sorry if I was rude sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need parse anything - you already have ready to use JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Try `var test = JSON.parse(json);`

Comment: What would it change? The JSON object is valid

Comment: That's true, it shouldn't solve his problem. But maybe it gives us further insight about what went wrong.

Comment: When i use it as as alert(result[0]); i receive [object Object] at fiddler

Comment: @tfeseas: use `console.log` instead